# How to generate and guarantee unique values in firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, consistency

Lets say we have a `order` collection in firestore where each order needs to have a unique **readable** random order number with lets say 8 digits:

```
{
    orderNumber: '19456734'
}
```

So for every incoming order we want to generate this unique number. What is the recommended approach in firestore to make sure no other document is using it?

*Note*: One solution would be querying existing docs before saving, but this is not working in a concurrent scenario where multiple orders arrive at the same time (?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest to guarantee that some value is unique in a collection, is to use that value as the key/ID for the documents in that collection. Since keys/IDs are by definition unique in their collection, this implicitly enforces your requirement.

The only built-in way to generate unique IDs is by [calling the `add()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document), which generates a UUID for the new document. If you don't want to use UUIDs to identify your orders, you'll have to roll your own mechanism.

The two most common approaches:

1. Generate a unique number and check if it's already taken. You'd do this in a transaction of course, to ensure no two instances can claim the same ID.
2. Keep a global counter (typically in a document at a well-known location) of the latest ID you've handed out, and then read-increment-write that in a transaction to get the ID for any new document. This is typically what other databases do for their built-in auto-ID fields.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that using the `add()` method will not incur any cost, while checking if a number already exists or keeping a global counter involve a document read, which has a (small) cost.