# Firebase firestore unique values in multiple fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql, unique

I'm creating an application for generating documents with unique id, my issue is that the id needs to be in a specific format ( 00000/A/B) so I can't use firestore document's id's.

The problem is also that I have that id's in different places,

#1 case

users/{userID}/id = //UNIQUE ID HERE

#2 case

users/{userID}/members <= members is an array of objects where every member need a unique id

I was thinking about the separate collection of id's where I can check which one is taken but maybe is there a better way to ensure id is unique across the whole app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're considering is pretty much the only way to guarantee uniqueness of a value across the database.

In a few more structured steps, it'd be:

- Use that value as the document ID in an secondary collection. This collection purely exists to ensure uniqueness of the IDs.
- Let the user claim it, typically by writing their UID into the document.
- Use security rules to ensure a user can only write a document if it doesn't exist yet, and (if needed) only deleted when they own it.

The topic of unique values has been covered quite a few times before, although usually in the form of unique user names, so I recommend checking out:

- [Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names/53032126)
- [How to generate and guarantee unique values in firestore collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213316/how-to-generate-and-guarantee-unique-values-in-firestore-collection)
- [How to enforce Uniqueness in a Property of a document field in Google Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68073767/how-to-enforce-uniqueness-in-a-property-of-a-document-field-in-google-cloud-fire)
- [Firestore unique index or unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543251/firestore-unique-index-or-unique-constraint)
- [I want to make unique usernames in firebase/firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111638/i-want-to-make-unique-usernames-in-firebase-firestore)