# Duplicate document in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create unique documents for each image I am uploading in a firebase collection.

This is my code for creating a document:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { projectStorage, projectFirestore, timestamp } from '../firebase-config';

const useStorage = (file) => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // references
    const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(file.name);
    const collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection('images');
    
    storageRef.put(file).on('state_changed', (snap) => {
      let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
      setProgress(percentage);
    }, (err) => {
      setError(err);
    }, async () => {
      const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
      const createdAt = timestamp();
      await collectionRef.add({ url, createdAt });
      setUrl(url);
    });
  }, [file]);

  return { progress, url, error };
}

export default useStorage;
```

But I'm getting two documents, for one image.

[the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw18w.png)
[the duplicate post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU80n.png)

Answer (score -1):

Every time you call `collectionRef.add` it creates a new document with its own unique ID. If you want something to be unique within a collection, it is best to use that value as the document ID within that collection and [set the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document) based on that ID rather than adding a new document each time.

So for example:

```
await collectionRef.doc(new firebase.firestore.FieldPath(url)).set({ url, createdAt });
```

Now the URL is used to identify the document, so by definition there will be only one document for each unique URL.

Also see:

- [How to enforce Uniqueness in a Property of a document field in Google Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68073767/how-to-enforce-uniqueness-in-a-property-of-a-document-field-in-google-cloud-fire)
- [Firestore unique index or unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543251/firestore-unique-index-or-unique-constraint)
- [How to generate and guarantee unique values in firestore collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213316/how-to-generate-and-guarantee-unique-values-in-firestore-collection)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but now i'm facing a new trouble, no document is being created now

Comment: yes your answer definitely made sense, but whenever I am using Fieldpath, I'm facing a new error : 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Class constructor FieldPath cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at Observer.complete

Comment: That seems like a typo in my answer. Did you try to fix that by adding `new` in front of `firebase.firestore.FieldPath` as the error message says?